# boost serialization save to multiple archive types and prevent construction of new object when loading with pointer

Tags: c++, design-patterns, boost, boost-serialization

I am using boost serialization to save objects from multiple archive outputs (  xml , binary and text ). When the library loads through pointer it creates a new object, and I want to prevent that for some of my objects, say for my dialog classes. So I am loading the dialogs with reference. But the code is ugly :

```
boost::archive::xml_iarchive ia;
for(vector<BaseDialog*>::iterator it= dialogs.begin();it!=dialogs.end();it++)
{
    if(typeid(it) == MyDialog1)
    {
         MyDialog1* dlg = dynamic_cast<MyDialog1*>(it);
         ia & (*dlg);
    }

    if(typeid(it) == MyDialog2)
    {
         MyDialog2* dlg = dynamic_cast<MyDialog2*>(it);
         ia & (*dlg);
    }              
}
```

So I came up with the following solution :

```
class BaseDialog
{
 public:
    virtual void SaveState(boost::archive::xml_oarchive& oa)=0;
    virtual void LoadState(boost::archive::xml_iarchive& ia)=0;
    virtual void SaveState(boost::archive::binary_oarchive& oa)=0;
    virtual void LoadState(boost::archive::binary_iarchive& ia)=0;
    // other formats here
};
```

In my derived classes I am implementing this functions. And the saving and loading is then something like this :

```
boost::archive::xml_iarchive ia;
for(vector<BaseDialog*>::iterator it= dialogs.begin();it!=dialogs.end();it++)
     it->LoadState(ia);
```

So , for each archive output I have  virtual function pair in the BaseDialog class, which is not good as well.

So anyone has idea how to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

`boost::serialization` can serialize a derived type through its base without problems. Take a look at [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html#registration) link.

Comment: if I serialize through base pointer it will create new object , which is not what I want